# Is there a 'deployer' native node js equivalent of Meteor's MeteorUp

Tags: node.js, express

Deploy Meteor apps is simple with [MUP](http://meteor-up.com/). The key feature here is that it has a docker implementation which is very useful and my team uses this a lot.

Now I'm doing a native  express.js app but I can't find nothing similliar to MUP where I just need to set the config file and done. I just find weird that there is not a 'deploy manager' for native node.js apps;

I've checked PM2, almost gets the job done, but can's send directly to the docker image.

Thanks.

Comment: I find it more productive to write the devops code myself rather than rely on some tool which invariably does a partial job then you waste time battling edge cases ... especially once you start scaling up with many of everything then need to have a webhook perform all the rebuild/redeploy  ... owning the full stack of devops tooling is liberating and empowering ...

Comment: This question may need to be edited to be more succinct.  What are you really asking?  It seems to be motivated by going from a "full-service" framework (meteor) to a more minimalist framework (express).  Typically in nodejs as with most languages, you write a program, then you run it, and it runs until it stops for some reason like a bug or an exit command. Node doesn't choose for you how recovery, hot loading, remote management, etc. occur though you can certainly write all that in node, and end up with something like Meteor or something else.